# PDO is unable to fetch database name on SQL queries

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to connect to the database via PDO and my `db.php` file is as follows:

```
$host = "localhost";
$db = "mydb";
$user = "user";
$pass = "qRES2fIWK8Gg";

try 
{
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host = $host; dbname = $db", $user, $pass);
    $db -> exec ("SET NAMES utf8"); // charset = utf8 doesn't work.
    echo "Database connection is successful. <br>";
}

catch (PDOException $e) 
{
    echo $e -> getMessage();
}
```

I have two problems which I think there is a connection between them.

1. When I check the `db.php`, I can get `Database connection is successful` message even though I change the `host` and `dbname` with random and incorrect values. How is that possible? When I try the same process on the database username and password, it gives an error.
2. I am unable to run SQL queries without stating database name in it as PDO
   doesn't fetch database name from `db.php`. For example, this SQL query
   doesn't work:

   ```
       SELECT * FROM settings WHERE settings_id= :id
   ```

   However, this one works successfully:

   ```
       SELECT * FROM mydb.settings WHERE settings_id= :id
   ```

I was working on localhost. After this problem, I thought it has been related to localhost and I moved my project to a virtual host. However, this step hasn't fixed the problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the spaces in your DSN string should resolve your issues:

```
"mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db"
```

Comment: I cannot believe that the answer to the problem that I had to deal with for two days is so easy :) Thanks! @Guillaume Boudreau